# Redux silently not rendering connect()ed component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am writing an app using Redux and can't get a Redux `connect()`ed component to render at all.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

var store = createStore((s, a) => s, {hello: "WORLD"});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() { return <h1> Hello, world! </h1>; }
}
var connectedApp = connect(function(s) { debugger })(App);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var target = document.getElementById("root");

  // DOES render
  React.render(<App/>, target);

  // Never renders
  React.render(<connectedApp/>, target);
});
```

The app is using babel, babelify, redux and redux-react.

Returning an object inside of connect() did not seem to modify `this.props` in the component, either. The `debugger` statement passed to `connect` never fires.

Is there something wrong with this code? Why isn't the component rendering? Why does the `debugger` statement never fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX converts component types that start with a capital letter into `React.createElement` calls to that type:

```javascript
<App/> // => React.createElement(App);
```

However, it converts component types that start with lowercase letters into DOM nodes (by passing it as a string instead of a reference):

```javascript
<connectedApp/> // => React.createElement("connectedApp");
```

In fact, if you look at the DOM via your browser's inspector, you'll likely see

```javascript
<connectedApp data-reactid=".0"></connectedApp>
```

Try capitalizing `connectedApp`:

```javascript
var ConnectedApp = connect(...)(App);

// ...

React.render(<ConnectedApp/>, target);
```

Comment: That's brutal (I've been messing around for hours trying to understand what I've done wrong with my app!)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a valid ReactElement to your second render method.

The first `<App/>` component is valid an therefor is being rendered as a DOM node.

The second `<connectedApp/>` however is not a ReactElement. So it won't be rendered at all. It is just a function. `var connectedApp = connect(function(s) { debugger })(App);`

Taken from the [API from REDUX](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) the typical use of the `connect` function is as follows:

`connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])(App)`

with the arguments:

**`[mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function)`**

The `App` component subscribes to the redux store updates, and this function is always called if the component updates. The return of this function should be a object.

**`[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function)`**

As object, every function inside will be recognized as a valid **action creator**

You don't need to pass the `connect` to a render method, just subscribe your `App` to the REDUX store.

So taken from the official REDUX page, this is how you set up the subscription:

```
import { React } from 'react'
import * as actionCreators from './actionCreators'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { todos: state.todos }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch) }
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  //your App
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)`
```